# Entering values and exiting if a blank line has been entered

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm trying to allow a user to continuously add a key and a value that are separated a space to a dictionary, with the option of allowing a user to finish entering keys and values by exiting when a blank line has been input.

So for example this is valid input:

```
test-string 12345
hello world
```

My code works fine however if a user enters only a single line and then a blank line then it's still displaying that invalid input has been entered:

```
Console.WriteLine("Parameters separated by a space (NAME - VALUE). A blank line ends input.");
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

while (Console.ReadLine() != String.Empty)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] splitInput = input.Split(' ');

    if (splitInput.Count() < 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");   
    }
    else
    {
        parameters.Add(splitInput[0], splitInput[1]);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where it's going wrong, I think it's to do with the `< 2` but I don't know how else to check the number of elements. How do I correctly allow for a number of values to be inputted with exiting on a blank line?

Comment: use the debugger and you will quickly see where you are going wrong in your logic

Comment: I suggest you change your `while` loop to `while (input = Console.ReadLine() != String.Empty)` to avoid skipping input.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a Console.ReadLine() inside of your while loop. Any empty line which is provided there is then split on a space, resulting in a string array with 0 elements. That's then immediately caught as "Invalid input."